# R package ‘rmr2’ is not installed for 'arch=i386'

Tags: r, hadoop

I was able to install the rmr2 package without any error, however when I attempt to load the package I receive the following error message:

```
    > library(rmr2)
Error: package ‘rmr2’ is not installed for 'arch=i386'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘rmr2’ was built under R version 3.0.1
```

I am running a 32 bit version of R on Windows 7; anyone have any suggestions on how to correct this problem??